# how to derive this negative sampling approximation for graphs?

Tags: machine-learning, graphs, graph-neural-network

I am watching CS224W video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xv0wRy66Big&list=PLoROMvodv4rPLKxIpqhjhPgdQy7imNkDn&index=8) and have some issue understanding the following approximation:

[image]

Does anyone have idea how this sigmoid appears in the approximation? I googled "log-sum-exp" trick but still have no clue how to derive it, any help would be much appreciated.